# ASP.Net MVC5 check if class is already in memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

For an intranet application I build a MVC5 website. I need a very large class object with a lot of data in my model and for security reasons the class hat to be build every call of the method, i.e.

```
largeClass = new LargeClassObject(param1, param2);
```

At the end of the function the garbageCollector works to dispose the class. That works fine. Sometimes, maybe when the intranet breaks, it is possible the method is not correct ending and the class stays in memory.
How can I detect on the next call wether a previous copy of this class exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit your class from IDisposable:

```
public class LargeClassObject : IDisposable
{
   var disposed = false;
   var handle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);

   public void Dispose()
   { 
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);           
   }

   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
      if (disposed)
         return; 

      if (disposing) {
         handle.Dispose();
      }

      disposed = true;
   }
}
```

Then just do this:

```
public void Main()
{
    using(var largeClass = new LargeClassObject(param1, param2))
    {
        try
        {
            DoSomethingWithObject(largeClass);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Do any additional cleanup
        }
    }
}
```

Now whether this works for you depends on your specific requirements, but `largeClass` will be purged from memory when any error happens during execution.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help. :)